# SSMS "Print" command doesn't meet conditions for scalar expression

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I want to print the result of an expression in SSMS v18.4:

```
PRINT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table)
```

but I get an error message:

> Msg 1046, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed

Why does the expression above not meet the conditions for scalarity?

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you the problem, you aren't allowed to use subqueries. Declare a variable, assign it's value, and then `PRINT` that:

```sql
DECLARE @C int;
SELECT @C = COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.YourTable;
--Or alternatively, if you prefer:
--SET @C = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.YourTable;
PRINT @C;
```

This limitation is also confirmed in the documentation: [PRINT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/print-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments):

> ### Arguments
>
> msg_str
> Is a character string or Unicode string constant. For more information, see Constants (Transact-SQL).
>
> @ local_variable
> Is a variable of any valid character data type. @local_variable must be char, nchar, varchar, or nvarchar, or it must be able to be implicitly converted to those data types.
>
> string_expr
> Is an expression that returns a string. Can include concatenated literal values, functions, and variables. For more information, see Expressions (Transact-SQL).

Notice none of the options are for a (sub-)query to be used.